# How to loop cy.task according to the result

Tags: random, promise, cypress, node-oracledb, cypress-task

I'm testing the CRUDs for a page in my application, where a registry requires an unique ID as a 5 digit number to be successfully created.

I would like to get a random available ID of that table to use in the tests, that can be achieved with the following sql query:

```js
    cy.task(
      'sqlQuery',
      `select count(*) as "count" from clients where client_id = '${
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000
      }'`
    )
```

The point is that the random number perhaps is not available to be used as the ID, so i would need to loop this same task until the generated number is available:

```js
    cy.task(
      'sqlQuery',
      `select count(*) as "count" from clients where client_id = '${
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000
      }'`
    ).then((result: any) => {
      if (result.rows[0].count === 0) {
        // My code to submit the form with the generated number
        // break the loop
      } else {
        // Repeat all of this (where i'm asking for help)
      }
    })
```

If count returns 0 it means it's there's no registry using it, otherwise it's not available.

I guess the final solution could be using some while loop, but I found this way would be more clear to you all know what i'm needing.

I tried some approachs like this, but just discovery that its impossible to assign a new value to a  variable inside the .then block, so it seems like i did an endless loop.

```js
    let available = false
    do {
      cy.task(
        'sqlQuery',
        `select count(*) as "count" from clients client_id = '${
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000
        }'`
      ).then((result: any) => {
        if (result.rows[0].count === 0) {
          // Code to submit the form with the generated number
          available = true
        }
      })
    } while (available === false)
```

Comment: You can't get it from the `auto_increment` value? Something like `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'clients'`, or make a query from `information_schema`

Comment: Right, this could be the solution for a single register step, but actually, in order to optimize time, I have 3 files with this kind of test running simoutaneously. Individualy they run ok using the `auto_increment` , but with the parallel run they'll all be doing registrations getting the same ID, and some will eventually fail later on the registration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask SQL what ids are present and check the random one against those?

Something like this:

```js
cy.task('sqlQuery', 'select client_id from clients')
  .then((result: any) => {
    const ids: string[] = result.rows;

    function getNewId(trys = 0) {
      if (trys > 1000) throw new Error('failed')
      const newId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000
      if (ids.includes(newId)) {
        return getNewId(++trys)
      }
      return newId
    }

    const newId = getNewId()
    cy.wrap(newId).as('newId')
  })
```

**Update**

Changed to a recursive javascript function, as I found when testing `.should()` it does not re-evaluate  `Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000`

---

It's been a while since I did some SQL, but maybe this correlated subquery is more efficient

```sql
SELECT last + 1 as newId FROM (
  SELECT MAX(id) as last FROM clients
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `Ids` array will contain all the already used IDS, which means it's not possible to create new registries with them. Actually I want the reverse, to get an available ID. This could be achieved with one more array declaration, but I think it could be not so performatic since ID can be up to 5 digit number, do you have any idea to this?

Comment: Ok, I saw in your SQL `clients client_id = '${random...`. You can make a function, either javascript or with Cypress `.should()`. I will add above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was pretty close to a soluction, but it was still returning unavailable ids, not sure but i think it's because ids at this point was not an array with only the actual id values, but an object with the columnname and value. I just altered the condition to use some accessing the id value instead, and its solved :) just going to improve the typage later. thanks again, was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this to get 3 unused IDs for your tests

MySQL:

```sql
SELECT a.id+1 as 'ids'
  FROM clients a
  WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clients b WHERE a.id+1 = b.id) AND
    a.id+1 < 100000
  ORDER BY a.id
  LIMIT 3
```

Oracle 11:

```sql
SELECT a.id+1 as ids
  FROM clients a
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clients b WHERE a.id+1 = b.id) AND
    a.id+1 < 10000 AND
    rownum <= 3
  ORDER BY a.id;
```

Oracle 12:

```sql
SELECT a.id+1 as ids
  FROM clients a
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clients b WHERE a.id+1 = b.id) AND
    a.id+1 < 10000
  ORDER BY a.id
  FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

This will search for unused IDs checking always the next ID, limiting it to 3 rows (you can limit the amount you need) to improve performance. And only available IDs, under 100000 (has only 5 digits)

---

For example:

Your table has de IDs `(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10)`

This query will check if the IDs `(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11)` exist in the table. If it doesnt exists, it will return. So this example will return `(2, 4, 8)`